# Delete every second row and column from spatial point data in R

Tags: r, r-raster, resampling

I have converted a raster to a point matrix in R. The file has 3 columns, x (lon), y (lat) and v (pixel value) - I am now looking to delete every second column by x and every second row by y as shown in the upper left corner of the image but am at loss how to do this. The idea is to thin the data without any interpolation or resampling.

Sample data as shown can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGEPsPEyrVNLEcZy-C6ES5915kWIaqGz/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking an R question, please always include a *minimal reproducible, self-contained example*, that is show some code and do not rely on files that must be downloaded.

As you started out with raster data, it is probably easiest to manipulate the raster data before creating points.

With the `raster` package:

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=20, ncol=20, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

p <- rasterToPoints(r)
plot(r)
points(p, cex=.5)
```

Solution

```
i <- seq(1, nrow(r), 2)
j <- seq(1, ncol(r), 2)
r[i,] <- NA
r[, j] <- NA
pp <- rasterToPoints(r)
points(pp, pch=20, cex=2)
```

Or with the `terra` package:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=20, ncol=20, xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1 +datum=WGS84")
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
p <- as.points(r)

plot(r)
points(p, cex=.5)

i <- seq(1, nrow(r), 2)
j <- seq(1, ncol(r), 2)
r[i,] <- NA
r[, j] <- NA
pp <- as.points(r)

points(pp, pch=20, cex=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Hard to know what to manipulate without a reproducible example and desired output, but this should remove even rows and columns from your matrix.

```r
library(dplyr)
matrix(1:100, nrow = 10) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  filter(row_number() %% 2 != 0) %>%
  select(seq(1, ncol(.), 2)) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think this is due to the fact that I am dealing with spatial data but as a dataframe here. It does the trick on the matrix and removes the second column but that is my y column. I think this needs to be treated as a spatial dataset in order to remove by x (lon) and y (lat) as shown in the image. I've added a link to a sample dataset, maybe that helps. Many thanks for the code though!